# Creating Dynamic Classes in Jade/Pug

Tags: pug, interpolation, dynamic-class-creation

I'm trying to add a dynamic class to a jade template. Like so:

```
- var obj = {a: 1, b: 2, c: 3};
- var len = Object.keys(obj).length;

.abc-#{len}
```

But the compiler is taking exception to this:

```
  > 4| .abc-#{len}
------------^

Unexpected token `interpolation` expected `text`, `interpolated-code`, `code`, `:`, `slash`, `newline` or `eos`
```

I've tried everything I could think of. Been scouring https://pugjs.org/language/interpolation.html. Could really use a hand.

Thanks.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You can do this:

`div(class="abc-"+len)`

attributes are interrupted automatically, more about [attributes](https://pugjs.org/language/attributes.html)

Comment: The class value can also be an array: `div(class=['foo', 'bar', 'baz']`

Answer (score 9):

You can use ES6 template literals as well. E.g.

```
div(class=`static_${dynamic_variable}`
```

In your case:

```
div(class=`abc-${len}`)
```

Have fun.